# VBA userform textbox enter event called twice for different textboxes

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, userform

I have an excel file where users use an userform to process data.
The userform is setup with frames in frames and textboxes within the inner frames.

I can't find any similar question on SO about this issue so here goes:

I am having the following issue due to the focus going to the textbox with `Tabindex 1` within the frame first instead of the textbox selected by the user (within a frame there are 6 textboxes which could be loaded with data).
The user can select any of the 6 textboxes to alter data so there is never an exact order of which textbox will be selected.

See below a picture of a part from the userform layout.

[image: Frame within frame with textbox]

The issue this creates is that when an user wants to alter the data that is in the textbox it gets emptied to garuantee the correct data is put in.

_enter() event code:

```
Private Sub Art1Aan1_Enter()
    Art1Aan1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

- Is there anyway to stop this from happening?
- or would i have to build in a safe check within the enter event to check wether the user really selected that textbox?

if option 2 then i can figure it out :)

**Edit/Update:**

Initiliase code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With Protocol.Product
   .AddItem "ID-1"
   .AddItem "ID-3"
   .AddItem "stans+CMI"
   .AddItem "Knip en Plak"
   .AddItem "Test"
End With

With Protocol.Product1
   .AddItem "ID-1"
   .AddItem "ID-3"
   .AddItem "stans+CMI"
   .AddItem "Knip en Plak"
   .AddItem "Test"
End With

With Protocol.Product2
   .AddItem "ID-1"
   .AddItem "ID-3"
   .AddItem "stans+CMI"
   .AddItem "Knip en Plak"
   .AddItem "Test"
End With
OrderKeuze_Lijst
End Sub
```

Userform start code (this gets called in a simple overview userform with 4 buttons):

```
Private Sub Protbutton_Click()
    Protocol.Show
End Sub
```

**Update:**

Hereby the [File](http://we.tl/Kxe9ND50WJ), the data inside is cleared.

Comment: Just change the `TabIndex` within your UserForm to ensure that the textbox you want is selected first. Note, that frames have also a tab stop. So, if you want textbox1 in frame1 to be first then the frame1 needs to get tabstop 0 and also textbox1 in frame1 should get tabstop 0 (zero). Furthermore, you can even set `TabStop` to false on the text box you don't want to change (or disable it entirely). Finally, you can use the frame events to make sure that the focus is going where you want it to be: `Art1Aan1.SetFocus`.

Comment: @ralph i will edit my question also, but the problem is there are 6 textboxes which some or all get loaded with data the user can select any textbox to be altered. This can be different every time the user uses the userform, thus its no use to alter the tabindex as its never know which textbox will be selected.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand the problem / question. Still, if you want something to stop from happening then don't code it. So, you choose which textbox gets emptied when you enter it. For each textbox there is a seperate `event` when you enter it and when you exit it. So, YOU can used these events (for each textbox seperately) to control what happens with each textbox upon entry and exit. The other problem "user clicks one thing and something different gets a focus" I cannot explain. I have never heard of something similar. When I click something then this gets normally the focus.

Comment: @Ralph I have for every textbox (that requires it) an enter `event` (the 3 line code above changed per textbox) . The problem lies in that for some reason VBA/Excel puts the focus on the textbox with `tabindex 1` first even if textbox with `tabindex 4` gets selected by the user. Just like you this is for me the first time to experience this problem and I have no idea why it happens.

Comment: @Ralph should i rephrase my question and explain in better detail what happens to better understand the problem? or is it fine the way it is but just a complicated problem?

Comment: If you are saying that Excel is doing things which you haven't programmed and which can be only interpreted as a bug in Excel then this is no topic for SO but something which you should note as a bug report to Microsoft (if everything is as you say). I just doubt it because I have never seen or read about a problem like this. I'd recommend that you have a closer look at your file or that you post the file here for us to have a look at. I am pretty sure you are just not seeing / overlooking something.

Comment: @Ralph I have googled more and used `Me.ActiveControl.SelectedItem.ActiveControl.Name` to double check which textbox gets focus first. this ends up being the textbox with `Tabindex 0` no matter which Textbox is selected. So far i also read (user comment on website)and noticed with this that this is how Excel functions. When it enters a frame by default the `Tabindex 0` gets first focus before "refocusing" on which ever control was originally selected by user. now i wonder should i rephrase my question and answer wit what i found + that then using a "Hidden"  textbox would be the best hack?

Comment: I am almost certain to know what the problem is. In order to verify my assumption please post your code which you are using to initiate, load, and show the form to the user including the code to set the focus (which does not seem to work at the moment). Then the problem will become obvious.

Comment: @Ralph see the update in my question, there is no code to get focus on a specific textbox. Its simply clicking on the textbox that should fire the event, but as stated in the last comment it always first fires the event in a frame of Tabindex 0 (which ever "type" that is).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87445/discussion-between-dragonsamu-and-ralph).

Comment: @Ralph i added the file finally, sorry for the delay.

Comment: sorry m8 I totally forgot about that >.<

Comment: @Ralph new link, sorry again >.<

Comment: @Ralph any luck yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, there have been a few obstacles. First of all your file is simply not working. Maybe that's because it is empty and you have removed all data within. Furthermore, there are no comments within documenting what were trying to achieve. Finally, you coded partially in your local language instead of English (for variables, sheet names, sub names, etc.). So, it was somewhat cumbersome to look into it.

Comment: I am getting one error message after the other. Finally, I merely tried to used the form in question `Protocol`. So, I started it directly from the VBE using F5. Still, the form won't even load and I don't know anymore where to start debugging. It seems to me that you have more than one problem within your code. Do you have a working version of this file (where only the problem you described occurs)?

Comment: @Ralph sorry for the trouble you are having. I forgot to think about the working factor just directly uploaded it. I will make a test version including Test documents so you can properly check it. (besides the naming issues and lack of more proper documentation still need to finish that)